# Can't fetch multiple rows from table

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm making a page which needs to display all the rows stored in a table named 'events' in a database named 'school'

The problem is that even though I've multiple entries/rows in the table, for some reason only a single row is displayed when I run the page.

Here's my code-

```
<?php
require("includes/common.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM school.events";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query)or die(mysqli_error($con));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$ename = $row['name'];
$place = $row['place'];
$date = $row['date'];
?>
.
.
.
<?php
while ($row) {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $ename; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $place; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $name = $row['name'];
    $place = $row['place'];
    $date = $row['date'];
}
?>
```

Comment: @clearshot66 I tried. Now it wouldn't even the display the one row it was displaying earlier.

Answer (score 2):

Try instead while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ... } , you're just assigning the array to $row, you can't loop an array saying while($array)

Do it this way:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo $row['id'];
   echo $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: I changed the while loop condition to what you're suggesting, but not even a single row is displayed now. Does it have something to do with storing the values retrieved in variables first and then displaying them? Coz that's what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2):

That is because `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` will only pull one row and then move the pointer. In order to get all the rows, use a while loop

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     //code to populate table one row at a time
}
```